# Elastic search + LogStash cannot connect

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, docker-compose

I'm trying to create an Elastic search installation using docker containers.
I'm using only elastic.io provider's images.

I'm encountering an error when starting my logstash instance.

Here is my configurations :

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.2.2
    container_name: elasticsearch1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    mem_limit: 1g
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet
  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.2.2
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch1"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    mem_limit: 1g
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet
      
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:5.2.2
    container_name: logstash
    mem_limit: 1g
    links: 
      - elasticsearch1:elasticsearch
    volumes: 
      - ./logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
    driver: bridge
```

an now my logstash.yml

```yaml
node: 
  name: 'default logstash'
http: 
  host: elasticsearch
pipeline:
  workers: 1
  batch:
    size: 12
    delay: 5
log: 
  level: 'debug'
```

I don't know why but logstash tell me that he cannot connect to the ElasticSearch instance with this error message:

```
...
[DEBUG][logstash.runner] *http.host: "elasticsearch" (default: "127.0.0.1")
...
[DEBUG][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] config LogStash::Ouputs::ElasticSearch/@hosts = [http://localhost:9200]
[INFO][logstash.ouputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>:removed>[], :added=>[logstash_system:xxxxx@localhost:9200/_xpack/monitoring/?system_id=logstash&system_api_version=2&interval=1s]}}
```

Could someone tell me why logstash is using a bad host event if he really got my settings?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the elasticsearch node on via a HTTP request on the port 9200?

Comment: It seems that Logstash is not pointing to the elasticsearh event. Not a communication problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution by replacing my logstash.yml by a logstash.conf file :

```
    input {
      stdin { }
      beats {
        port => 5044
      }
    }

    output {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts    => [ 'elasticsearch' ]
        user     => 'elastic'
        password => 'changeme'
      }
    }
```

Finally, I change my docker-compose file to link this conf file:

```
    volumes: 
      - ./logstash-pipeline/:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/
```

Comment: Please let me know if any XPack required to be installed at Logstash side (version 5.6.5) for such basic authentication. The Elasticsearch server that I am going to use seems to be somehow added such basic authentication newly which I should use now at the Logstash end.

Comment: If your ES is using authentication aka x-pack, then yes, your logstash also needs to install the plugin and you need to use `user, password` in logstash.conf file while connecting to elasticsearch